# Elasticsearch mapping - asciifolding filter

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, ascii

I have a mapping:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "refresh_interval": "-1",
            "number_of_shards": "4",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "lower_ascii": {
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding"
                        ],
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "field_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "lower_ascii",
                    "fielddata": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is asciifolding and lowercase filter set up in mapping. But the values of the field are not in ascii nor in lowercase? There are raw strings like "Námestie Ludvíka Svobodu"... Am I missing something or don't understand it right? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I did not understand what you need. This analyzer is used when indexing. It means you now can do a search by "namestie" in lowercase and you will get your document.

Comment: yes, mapping gets defined based on how the data should look like before you indexed (inserted) the data (documents) in an index. So if you have data that does not fit the mapping then it will look for `dynamic`. in your case the value of `dynamic` is `strict` meaning it wont index the document that does not fit the mapping. Is this what you wanted to know or you have a question? please elaborate more if this does not help you with your original question

Comment: @JBone The question is about lower_ascii analyer not about dynamic.

Comment: @Gillespie59 So the data are stored in raw format as they come to database BUT are indexed as ascii and lowercase? My confusion is caused by what I see is not an index but raw data?

Comment: Maybe this will help you. The `_source` field in the documents is not what is indexed by elasticsearch, it is the content of the document you sent. So yes it may contains non ascii characters. To get the indexed content, you must use the [_termvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) endpoint. E.g., `GET /<INDEX>/_termvectors/<DOC_ID>?fields=field_name`

Comment: Thanks for help. I will test it.

Comment: if you want to change the _source data at indexing time, I suggest looking at [ingest processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html)